# Yacc parser not reducing specific production rules as intended

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, text-parsing

I am trying to implement a parser using yacc, and I have encountered an issue where the parser is not reducing a `midline` in the provided excerpt.

I understand that this a shift/reduce conflict, and that yacc's default is to shift. It is not clear to me how this can be amended, however -- all examples I have seen involve simple infix operators involving precedence and associativity. I have included the excerpt below, and the full code can be found with the appropriate commit permalinked on [GitHub](https://github.com/jcai849/underline-midline/commit/14a45e18484b2d43caf4f753ee17fb7418562176).

```
...

%token MINUS UNDERSCORE TEXT

%%

accept:
    | accept phrase
    ;

phrase:
      text
    | phrase text
    ;

text:
      literal
    | formatted
    ;

literal: TEXT ;

formatted:
      midline
    | underline
    ;

midline: MINUS phrase MINUS ;

underline: UNDERSCORE phrase UNDERSCORE ;
```

I have tested this code using the simple test case `"The _cat -sat on- the_ mat"`, with the intention that in this case the `midline` nests within the `underline`. What happens is that neither `midline` nor `underline` are ever reduced to, and it fails with a syntax error.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is state 15? 5? 12? 3? 13? 4, 6, 1, 0?

Comment: @user207421 -- The linked repo has a makefile with the default target serving to generate the full output, and the "doc" target creating an html file describing each of the states. I felt it would be excessive detail to include full descriptions of all states in this post.

Comment: @user207421 -- edited to simplify. Please see the linked repo and follow the readme to reproduce the output and documentation of parser states.

Comment: I will not see the linked repository. Questions posted here must include all relevant information, here, in the question.